# Intent Set Deployment

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, package.xml, einstein-bots

Is there a way to deploy Intent Set from dev to production with all the existing utterance present in it.If it's possible can you share me an example of the package we need to create for that or if there is any other way we can achieve that?